# How to work smart on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, answers, tips

I have to admit that I work rather "primitively" most of the time, but I realize now that in order to increase my productivity I have to work smarter. Thus, I'm looking for guidance from the top users of Stack Overflow: how do you work efficiently? How do you work smart?

#### Automation

- How can I auto-link to, say, Java API? What do I need to do so that if I type `java.util.Set`, `String.split`, etc., it automatically generates the links?
- How can I auto-insert, say, canned footers? Many regular expressions questions, for example, can benefit from a references section to, say, regular-expressions.info. What do I need to do so that I can enable some sort of macro replacement or whatever, e.g., type `"re-info"`, `"bloch-cloneisbroken"`, etc. and have that be automatically replaced with predetermined texts?
- What do I need to do so that I can pretty much drag and drop links into my question, instead of typing it as text?

#### Searching into your own body of work

- Sometimes you want to pull parts of your own answers from the past, but this can be hard to find, e.g. if you forgot the question title, etc. How can I "Google" my own archive of answers?

#### An external editor?

I'd imagine the most effective way may involve an external editor that enables all these things, and then either copy/pasting it to Stack Overflow, or have it post to Stack Overflow through some sort of plug-in? I've heard some awesome stuff about TextMate, so perhaps this is what I need?

Then maybe I can somehow "import" all my past answers and build my own local searchable index or something? Then use Google Desktop or something?

Answer (score 2):

Well, as for "Searching into your own body of work" see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search specifically the `user:me` operator.

I also highly recommend installing and using a clipboard stack buffer tool, as documented here:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/01/reinventing-the-clipboard.html

Comment: A better clipboard management software, of course! Why didn't I think of that!